# How to see os.hostname() module from nodejs on html in a electron app?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, node-modules

this is my first post, so im sorry for anything.
I´m struggling trying to show the os.hostname() module from nodejs in a html page in a electron app, i get the hostname in the terminal, but i can´t get it to show on the app page when i run it.

This is the code i have:

Javascript
(index.js)

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Tray, Menu} = require('electron');
const os = require('os');

if(os.hostname()) {
    var hostname = os.hostname();
    console.log("Hostname for the operating system is " + String(hostname));
}

app.on('ready', () => {

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
         nodeIntegration: true
        }

    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
    tray = new Tray('pic.PNG')
    tray.setToolTip('Tray App')
    tray.on("click",() =>{
    mainWindow.isVisible()?mainWindow.hide():mainWindow.show()
    let template =[{label:'Hostname'},{label:'DNS'}]
    let contextMenu= Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
    tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)

    })
})
```

Html
(index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <Title>App</Title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img src="picbig.png" alt="logo" />
        <h1>Wellcome</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Hostname:<span id="Hostname"></span></p>
    <script src="renderer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope i got it clear, if anyone needs any additional info so you can help me, let me know please!
Thank you in advance.

I tried every way i could find to show a javascript var in html, but it didn´t work :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, i was missing a preload file to connect everything.

Here is the code(and ofc the package.json, but i wont show it cause it´s default when u create a new electron project):

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const os = require('os');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: __dirname + '/preload.js'
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

ipcMain.handle('getHostname', async (event, arg) => {
  return os.hostname();
});
```

preload.js

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ipcRenderer.invoke('getHostname').then(hostname => {
    document.getElementById('hostname').textContent = `Hostname: ${hostname}`;
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Electron App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="hostname"></h1>
    <script src="renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```